# Difference Process of a Strictly Stationary Process

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes

Let $\left\{X_n\right\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ be a **strictly stationary** process. Define the process $\left\{Y_n\right\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ as
$$Y_n=X_{n+1}-X_n,\forall n\in\mathbb{N}.$$
It's clear that the process $\left\{Y_n\right\}$ is **weakly stationary,** from the stationarity of $\left\{X_n\right\}.$

However, I'm unsure whether $\left\{Y_n\right\}$ is **strictly stationary.**

I'm looking forward to either a proof, or a counterexample for this proposition. All comments and ideas are appreciated.

> Saying $\left\{Y_n\right\}$ is **weakly stationary** means that:
>
> 1. $\mathbb{E}(Y_n)=\mu$ and $\textrm{Var}(Y_n)=\sigma^2<\infty,$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N};$
> 2. There exists a function $\gamma,$ called the *autocovariance* function satisfying
>    $$\textrm{cov}(Y_p,Y_q)=\gamma(|p-q|),\forall p,q\in\mathbb{N}.$$

> Saying $\left\{X_n\right\}$ is **strictly stationary** means that $\left\{X_n\right\}$ is **weakly stationary** and furthermore, for all $p,q\in\mathbb{N},$
> $$(X_1,X_2,...,X_p)\hspace{3mm}\textrm{and}\hspace{3mm}(X_{q+1},X_{q+2},...,X_{q+p})$$
> has the same joint distribution.

Comment: I'm looking for more context, e.g., what is your definition of strictly stationary, and weakly stationary?  The definitions will differ in some way.  Please use the definitions you have learned, and include that context in your post.  Thanks.

Comment: Thanks @amWhy for the suggestions; I have updated the relevant definitions.

Comment: It is not "clear" that the difference process is weakly stationary, because it's not true. Take iid $X_n \sim Cauchy$, for instance.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know, Jeff!